# www-embed-player.js:150 GET chrome-extension://eojlgccfgnjlphjnlopmadngcgmmdgpk/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILED

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, console, chromium

I've uninstalled / disabled all of my chrome's extensions  and this error keeps showing in the console. Any idea how to fix this? I would really appreciate...It's interrupting my debugging

Comment: should I install it ? Am not in incognito either

Comment: You've got a few options: 1) Ignore the error, 2) Install the extension 3) Bug the developers (YouTube) to fix their code.

Comment: 4) Silence the error by "Hide network messages" filter